# Regex to match content between string that doesn't include this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a string that start end end with a specific string like `[#start,` and `,#end]`. I use for that the regex `/\[#start,(.*?),#end\]/g`:

```js
const string = '[#start,foobar,#end]'
const regex = /\[#start,(.*?),#end\]/g

console.log(string.match(regex))
```

The next step is to add the condition that the match doesn't contains in the middle another match like for example `[#start,[#start,foobar,#end],#end]`. I use for that a negative look-arounds `/\[#start,((?!\[#start,(.*?),#end\]).*?),#end\]/g`:

```js
const string = '[#start,[#start,foobar,#end],#end]'
const regex = /\[#start,((?!\[#start,(.*?),#end\]).*?),#end\]/g

console.log(string.match(regex)) // --> will just match "[#start,foobar,#end]"
```

It's working well so far but the issue is that the start string is little bit more complex because it as to match something like `/"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",/g`. Example:

```js
const string = '"#for i in [1, 2]",{"id": "[i]"},"#endfor"'
const regex = /"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",(.*?),"#endfor"/g

console.log([...string.matchAll(regex)])
```

Again I don't want that the 'middle' contains this syntax so I use like the previous example a negative look-arounds `"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",(((?!"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",(.*?),"#endfor").)*?),"#endfor"`:

```js
const string = '"#for i in [1, 2]","#for i in [1, 2]",{"id": "[i]"},"#endfor","#endfor"'
const regex = /"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",(((?!"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",(.*?),"#endfor").)*?),"#endfor"/g

console.log(string.match(regex))
```

But in this case it still match the first occurance of `#for i in [1, 2]` instead of just the string in the middle `"#for i in [1, 2]",{"id": "[i]"},"#endfor"`. Any idea what is happening?

For those who wonder why such a regex, I need to use it in the development of the project [restapify](https://github.com/johannchopin/restapify) that enable you to easily mock a rest API with a JSON file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
#for ((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?) in ((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?)",((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?),"#endfor
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cabcNW/3)

**Code:**

```js
const string = '"#for i in [1, 2]","#for i in [1, 2]",{"id": "[i]"},"#endfor","#endfor"';

const regex = /#for ((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?) in ((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?)",((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?),"#endfor/g;

var m = [...string.matchAll(regex)]

if (m)
  console.log(m[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but here it should only match the string `"#for i in [1, 2]",{"id": "[i]"},"#endfor"` because it doesn't contain another `#for ...` syntax. In your example the first occurenance of `#for i in [1, 2]` is matched and that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just a tiny question. With my first regex `/"#for (.*?) in (.*?)",(.*?),"#endfor"/g`, I'm able with the `matchAll` method to get all the different components of my string (see my example in the updated question). Sadly with yours I only get the middle part. Do you have any idea what I need to update to have all the 3 different parts? :)

Comment: What are the expected matches for `const string = '"#for i in [1, 2]","#for i in [1, 2]",{"id": "[i]"},"#endfor","#endfor"';`? We can get same with my regex also by using: `#for ((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?) in ((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?)",((?:(?!#for .*? in .*?",|"#endfor).)*?),"#endfor`

Comment: You can see if you run the third code snippet that you got in the console multiple elements according to the multiple `(.*?)`. With this string the result should be `["\"#for i in [1, 2]\",{\"id\": \"[i]\"},\"#endfor\"", "i", "[1, 2]", "{\"id\": \"[i]\"}"]` but with yours regex I got `["#for i in [1, 2]\",{\"id\": \"[i]\"},\"#endfor", "{\"id\": \"[i]\"}"`. Any idea?

Comment: [You can see demo with my suggested regex](https://regex101.com/r/cabcNW/3). This shows your expected output.